# Could you help me with this integral: $\int\frac{\ln x-2}{x\sqrt{\ln x}} \, dx$?

Tags: integration

$$\int\frac{\ln x-2}{x\sqrt{\ln x}} \, dx$$

Could I ask you, please, for helping me out with this example? I have some issues to get an result of this… Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried doing this by simple substitution?

Comment: Yes, I am actually asked to do it with substitution, but I don't know what's just wrong...

Comment: Make sure you also substitute $dx$ with $du$ if you substitute $x$ with $u$.

Answer (score 6):

$$
\int\frac{\ln x - 2}{\sqrt{\ln x}} \underbrace{{}\ \left( \frac{dx}{x} \right)\ {}}_\text{HINT}
$$

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\int\frac{\ln x-2}{x\sqrt{\ln x}}dx=\int\frac{\sqrt{\ln x}}{x}dx-\int\frac{2}{x\sqrt{\ln x}}dx=\frac23(\ln x)^{3/2}-4\sqrt{\ln x}+C$$

Comment: I checked the correct results and there's this: $$2lnx(\frac{\ln x}{3} - 2) + C$$ -- however, I am still not able to get there.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y = \sqrt{\ln x} \to \ln x = y^2 \to x = e^{y^2} \to dx = 2y\cdot e^{y^2}\,dy$. So your integral equals to: $$\int 2y^2 - 4 \,dy = \dfrac{2y^3}{3} - 4y + C = \dfrac{2(\ln x)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3} - 4\sqrt{\ln x} + C$$

Comment: I changed several occurrences of $lnx$ to $\ln x$.  That is standard usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

$t= \sqrt{\ln x}$, then
$dt = (\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{\ln x}) dx = \frac{1}{2x\sqrt{\ln x}} dx $

So your integral becomes
\begin{equation*}
2\int (t^2 - 2) dt
\end{equation*}